# I am finding difficulty in designing complex table using css

Tags: html, css

Here is html code for table i am having disorentation problem in resulting table. Kindly help.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    background-color:#A6F7EE;

}

th {
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<th>State</th>
<th>Condition</th>
<th>Slab Low</th>
<th>Slab High</th>
<th>Rate(in Rs)</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td rowspan="4">Andhra Pradesh (As per tariff order dated 23rd March 2015.)</td>
<td colspan="3">Consumption less than 50 Units</td> <td align="center"> 1</td> <td align="center">50</td> <td align="center">1.45</td
></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Consumption between 1 & 100 Units <td>  1</td>  <td>50</td> <td>    1.45</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>51</td> <td>100</td>    <td>2.6</td>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Resulting table is disoriented what can be done to make table's row of equal size.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the question, but there were some problems with the closing tags in your code and one of the td rowspans, maybe that was why it wasn't rendering correctly. Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    background-color:#A6F7EE;

}

th {
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
    <th>Slab Low</th>
    <th>Slab High</th>
    <th>Rate(in Rs)</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Andhra Pradesh (As per tariff order dated 23rd March 2015.)</td>
    <td colspan="3">Consumption less than 50 Units</td><td>1</td><td>50</td><td>1.45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Consumption between 1 & 100 Units</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>1.45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>2.6</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If fixing the closing and opening tags doesn't work, then (following your screenshot) the HTML markup should be something like this (just change the values);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    table,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 80%;
      background-color: #A6F7EE;
    }
    th {
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>1a</th>
      <th>1b</th>
      <th>1c</th>
      <th>1d</th>
      <th>1e</th>
      <th>1f</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">2a</td>
      <td>2b</td>
      <td>2c</td>
      <td>2d</td>
      <td>2e</td>
      <td>2f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">3a</td>
      <td rowspan="2">3b</td>
      <td>3c</td>
      <td>3d</td>
      <td>3e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4c</td>
      <td>4d</td>
      <td>4e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5b</td>
      <td>5c</td>
      <td>5d</td>
      <td>5e</td>
      <td>5f</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pleasure to help, remember to accept the answer by clicking the green tick if it helped you!